# Using BitBucket repo in Github App (Mac OSX)

Tags: macos, github, bitbucket

I´m new to mac osx system and in windows i have set a repository from bitbucket in github app successfuly. Now in Mac OSX i can´t drag the url from the BitBucket page (and i pull the commits locally to bb). Is there a way to do this?? Sorry for my bad english!
Thanks for the future responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `clone` the repository locally and add it like they explain [here](http://mac.github.com/help.html#faq-add-repositories).

Alternatively, you can `clone` it directly from GitHub for Mac like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10197245/641451).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but maybe i don´t express well in the answer. I wanna commit the changes locally to bitbucket through github app (like i was doing in windows)

Comment: While using GitHub for Windows or GitHub for Mac (or `git` in general), you `commit` to a local `clone` of the remote repository, and then sync with it (`pull`/`push`). That's true working with a GitHub remote, a Bitbucket remote, or any `git` remote. So, the only difference between using the GitHub app with a non-GitHub remote is you can't clone it through their web interface clicking `Clone in Mac`/`Clone in Windows`.