# Can we use the Github mac app with GitLab?

Tags: macos, gitlab, github-for-mac

I like the GitHub Mac app, which I use with my GitHub account. I have joined a GitLab project and I was wondering whether I can use the GitHub app with a GitLab repository. I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639815/does-github-for-windows-work-with-gitlab) that discuss that the Windows GitHub app works with GitLab and [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325935/github-for-windows-with-gitlab-community-edition?lq=1) that show how to add a repo. Both these posts gave me hope that the GitHub Mac App would work with GitLab. I also [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281164/using-bitbucket-repo-in-github-app-mac-osx) that you can use BitBucket with the GitHub Mac app, but I don't understand whether and how to link a GitLab repository to my GitHub Mac app.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With the mac app, you have to do the clone on the command line. Open a terminal, navigate to directory that you want to be the parent of your local repo, and git clone the repo. As soon as this is done, go into the github mac app and Go to File->Add Local Repo

You can then add the repo directory file picker, and from there you should be set. The first time you push back to origin through the app, it will ask for your gitlab username and password, and optionally store them in the keychain.

Comment: Please share the commands or in detail.. I need to this urgently.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the command in terminal (OSX) that worked for me to clone the repo:

git clone git@gitlab.com:*yourusername*/*yourrepo*.git

Hope this helps someone